# codeigniter - display database query result on same form using input data

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have trawled the net for sometime now trying to find a solution which cold assist me, but have had no luck.

I have a simple sales form in which the user selects a product from a drop down list. on selecting a value, I want the input box value to get passed to a database query, and the query result (price) be displayed on the form. if possible I want the result to populate an input box so the salesman can adjust as needed.

I am using codeigniter which makes finding a good example quite difficult.

**Controller**

```
function new_blank_order_lines() 
  {
   $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines');
  }
```

**Model**

```
 function get_sku_price($q){
    $this->db->select('ProductPrice');
    $this->db->where('ProductCode', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('ProductList');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['ProductPrice'])); //build an array
      }
      $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($row_set));

    }
  }
```

**View**

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Product</td><td>Price</td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td><select name="product">
       <option="sku1">product 1</option>
       <option="sku2">product 2</option>
       <option="sku3">product 3</option>
   <select></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="price" name="price" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have loaded the jquery library, 1.9.1.

I have got autocomplete working but the sytax is just not the same.

So what I am wanting, is that when I select a product code from the `product` drop down list, the value is passed to the model, the query result(price) is then displayed in the input box `price`.

Can anyone provide some insight on how to do this, or a good working example?

Thanks a million, this community is awesome!

**Fabio**

Controller:

```
function new_blank_order_lines() 
  {
   $this->load->view('sales/new_order');
  }
```

The view:

```
<script>
$("#product").change(function () {
    //get the value of the select when it changes
    var value = $("#product").val()

    //make an ajax request posting it to your controller
    $.post('<?=base_url("sales/get_sku_prices")?>', {data:value},function(result) {
      //change the input price with the returned value
      $('#price').value(result);
    });
});
</script>
  <table>
  <tr><td>Product</td><td>Price</td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td><select name="product" id="product">
       <option value="sku1">product 1</option>
       <option value="sku2">product 2</option>
       <option value="sku3">product 3</option>
   </select></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="price" name="price" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Controller to fetch database data:

```
  function get_sku_prices(){
    //check if is an ajax request
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
        //checks if the variable data exists on the posted data
        if($this->input->post('data')){
            $this->load->model('Sales_model');
            //query in your model you should verify if the data passed is legit before querying
            $price = $this->your_model->get_sku_price($this->input->post('data', TRUE));

            echo $price;
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
  function get_sku_price($q){
    $this->db->select('ProductPrice');
    $this->db->where('ProductCode', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('ProductList');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['ProductPrice'])); //build an array
      }
      $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($row_set));

    }
  }
```

Comment: use jquery to create a listener for the change event on the select, when that event is fired the selected value is passed to that function, that will make an ajax request to one method on your controller responsible to receive the value, pass it to the model then the model will query your database, return the value to the controller and then the controller echo that value, then in the ajax success method you just put that value on the input textbox

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I am new to codeigniter and ajax / javascript so if you have an example or a good working link to read please let me know. Thanks,

Comment: Well let me write something for you, but it'll take a while

Comment: Thanks Fabio, appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your View:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
         <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="product" id="product">
                <option value="sku1">product 1</option>
                <option value="sku2">product 2</option>
                <option value="sku3">product 3</option>
            </select>
            </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The javascript

```
<script>
  $("#product").change(function () {
    //get the value of the select when it changes
    var value = $("#product").val()

    //make an ajax request posting it to your controller
    $.post('<?=site_url("controller/function")?>', {data:value},function(result) {
      //change the input price with the returned value
      $('#price').value(result);
    });
  });
</script>
```

The controller:

```
public function your_funtion(){
    //check if is an ajax request
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
        //checks if the variable data exists on the posted data
        if($this->input->post('data')){
            $this->load_model('your_model')
            //query in your model you should verify if the data passed is legit before querying
            $price = $this->your_model->get_price($this->input->post('data', TRUE));

            echo $price;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio, you are too generous. I will attempt this now and revert if any issues. thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again Fabio. tried to make the changes as per your advice. firebug is displaying error: `400 bad request` XHR shows error: `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.` I will update the question with my actual code for you to refer to. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello Fabio, I updated my question to assist. have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: put this  $this->load->helper('url'); on the beginning get_sku_prices()

Comment: sorry it's the new_blank_order_lines(), put this $this->load->helper('url') on the beginning.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I dont think this is the issue. I autoload the url helper in autoload.php. `$autoload['helper'] = array('cookie', 'form', 'url', 'security', 'date', 'array', 'string', 'file');`

Comment: Hi, post syntax should be: `$.post('sales/get_sku_prices', {data:value},function(result) {`. obviously is aware of the current folder location. Now receiving error: `$("#price").value is not a function`

Comment: Thanks Fabie, that is the code I have. error message is: `$("#price").value is not a function`. any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Hi Fabio. okay correct syntax (and thanks to you and SO community) is
`$("#price").val(result);`. Problem is that the default function (index) is being returned into input box (price). The entre html page is in the box rather than the echo result from model `get_sku_price`

Comment: that's because you're making an ajax request to your index and not the  get_sku_price, that's why I use <?=site_url("controller/function")?>

Comment: can you try using $.post('<?=site_url("your_controller/get_sku_price")?>', {data:value},function(result)

Comment: This leaves error: `value is not defined`.  
The site_url is not translating.
`$.post('<?=site_url("sales/get_sku_price")?>', {data:value},function(result)`

Comment: can you just use inspect element go to your javascript and check wich url is being generated with <?=site_url("sales/get_sku_price")?>

Comment: it comes up as just `$.post('<?=site_url("sales/get_sku_price")?>', {data:value},function(result)` that is in firebug and standard inspect element.

Comment: Is your view a html file? something like this view.html? If so change it to view.php

Comment: Well that's weird, it's not processing that as php but as a string or html. instead of using shortag try using the normal way <?php echo site_url("sales/get_sku_price")?>

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's ajax,[post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and change event..using post here

example..

```
 $('select[name="product"]').change(function(){
      var val=$(this).val();
      $.post('path/to/controller',{data:val},function(result){
          $('#price').val(result.price);
      }, "json");
 });
```

conroller funciton

```
$product=$this->input->post('data');  //this will give you the selected value of select
//make query to db in model..get price and
$price = ..//price that you got from db
echo json_encode(array('price'=> $price));
```

Comment: Thank you bipen. does this display the data without refreshing the page? would it use a separate function in the controller? any example or reading that I can look at that meets my requirement?

Comment: hmmm.. this does it wihtout refreshing the page... you need to create a seperate function in a controller that gets the required price by db query from the selected fields... and send it as response in JSON which i expalind in my answer in controller function part