# Codeigniter display data description based on selected dropdown id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to display in the text field the corresponding description of the dropdown id that I selected. I will be using it to minus the days that corresponds to that id to the actual days it took to process a paper labeling the result as days delayed to perform the process. Example of this is the process was label printing and the corresponding days to do it is only 3 days but the actual process finished after 4 days having a 1 day delay. I am using codeigniter but I am having errors like invalid method. Please help.

This is my controller,

```
$data['operation'] = $this->wip_model->get_operation();
```

This is the model,

```
function get_operation(){
    $this->db->select('OperationName');
    $this->db->select('DeliveryDays');
    $this->db->from('operation');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $result;
}
```

This is my view snippet,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Operation</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="operation" name="operation">
       <option value="">-SELECT-</option>
       <?php foreach($operation as $val){ ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $val['OperationName'];?>">
       <?php echo $val['OperationName'];?></option>
       <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('operation');?></span>
</div>
```

I tried to put a hidden textbox after the select option but I am having unexpected results like instead of displaying number of days corresponds to the selected value, it displays the next items to be displayed by select option. I hope my english is not that bad and may you get the logic that I am presenting...

I search and found this code:

```
function showDays(str){
    $.get("<?php echo site_url('wip/get_deliverydays');?>",{q:str},function(data){
        $("#deliverydays").html(data);
    });
}
```

I thought it will now work but I am having now a Uncaught ReferenceError: showDays is not defined...

Comment: Just a note you can use one select like so `$this->db->select('OperationName, DeliveryDays');`

Comment: Yes I already did that but I cannot display the days that corresponds to the selected value for example if I choose spotprint the number of days should be 3 days.

Comment: I am now checking this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509514/codeigniter-display-database-query-result-on-same-form-using-input-data if it can help me solve my problem...

Comment: Yes, if you get the logic that I posted...

Answer (score 0):

Model,

```
public function get_operation(){
    $this->db->select('OperationName,DeliveryDays,id');
    $this->db->from('operation');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}

public function fetch_result($posted_id){
    $this->db->select('OperationName,DeliveryDays');
    $this->db->from('operation');
    $this -> db -> where('id',$posted_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

In View,

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url().'Controller/action'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Operation</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="operation" name="operation" onchange="set_to(this.value)";>
        <option value="">-SELECT-</option>
        <?php foreach($operation as $val) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $val->id;?>"><?php echo $val->OperationName;?></option>
        <?php  } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="idesc" name="idesc"/>
    <input type="submit" name="reqsub" class="btn btn-primary">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function set_to(id){
    $('#idesc').val(id);
}

</script
```

In Controller,

```
 $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 $posted_id=$this->input->post('operation');
 $value['data']=$this->model->fetch_result($posted_id);
 $this->load->view('viewpage',$value);
```

In new view,

```
<?php

foreach($data as $row){
    echo $row->OperationName;
    echo $row->DeliveryDays;
}

?>
```

Comment: i wil try and inform you,please wait

Comment: i updated my code using javascript ,try this,surely u get

Comment: ok I will try your code but I will be having my lunch first so I might get in touch with you maybe after one hour.... thanks anyway for the help....

Comment: can I change the id to DeliveryDays because that is what I need to show instead of i?

Comment: what you really want to fetch on textbox? if deliverydays? then change it to deliverydays

Comment: I think your first code that you gave me is more suitable to solve my problem just make it display on to the same page as the dropdown....

Comment: when you select value from dropdown,that wil display on the textbox

Comment: What I need is a separate process for OperationName and DeliveryDays just like you're first code and not in one option value because I save the OperationName in the database I just need the DeliveryDays for reference.... Hope you still help me.....

Comment: <input type="text" id="idesc" name="idesc"/> is your id of textbox like this????? then only get.i updated my code